# Problema al heredar plantillas HTML en Django

Tags: python, django, herencia

Cuando intento heredar una plantilla **base** hacia otra plantilla **inico** y utilizo {% block content %} {% endblock %} en lugar de devolverme lo que tengo en el archivo base me devuelve texto. Ayuda porfavor, gracias de antemano. Adjunto mi codigo por si no quedo claro el problema.

[image: ARCHIVO BASE DE HTML]

[image: ARCHIVO INICIO QUE HEREDARA DE BASE.HTML]

[image: PAGINA QUE DEVUELVE EL TEXTO EN LUGAR DE EL CONTENIDO DE BASE]

Answer (score 0):

Bien por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

Esto sucede en Django porque se esta cargando el documento directamente en el navegador

Lo que se tiene que hacer es cargar el servidor con el siguiente comando en la carpeta donde se encuentra el proyecto `python manage.py runserver` de ese modo accedemos al navegador y vamos a la direccion que ahi se nos proporciona.